# Stuck with Java 8 stream usage

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn how to use Streams in Java 8 but am not sure how to go about it here.

I have a list of courses. I need to know if all the courses for a semester have no students, and if that is the case, do something. I came up with the below code but this is giving Null Pointer Exception as soon as any course gets iterated which doesn't have any students.I need to know how can i correct it:

```
List<Student> students = semester.getCourses().stream().flatMap(course -> course.getStudents().stream())
                .filter(Objects :: nonNull).collect(toList());
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(students)){
            //cancel the semester or do something
        }

public class Semester{

 int semId;
 List<Course> courses;
}

public class Course{
 int courseId;
 List<Student> students;
}
```

Comment: So.. you want to know if the courses all match the condition that their getStudents() is empty?

Comment: Yes. I need to know if there is no student present in all of the courses combined.

Comment: yes, I am hinting at the answer, you just have to add the correct punctuation to it... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the actual code the `NullPointerException` may come from `course` is `null` or `course.getStudents()` is `null`.
This filter `filter(Objects :: nonNull)` is helpless. It doesn't filter the `null` `Student`s and that is not your requirement.
This code should be what you are looking for :

```
List<Student> students = 
 semester.getCourses()
         .stream()
         .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter out null Course objects
         .map(Course::getStudents)  
         .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter out null Student List
         .flatMap(Collection::stream)                                        
         .collect(toList());
```

Note also that adding null checks everywhere is not good : it makes "real logic" less readable.
You can at least avoid these for collection fields by initializing them in their  declarations such as :

```
public class Semester{
 int semId;
 List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Course{
 int courseId;
 List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt here. Suppose the semester has 0 courses, then semester.getCourses().stream() will give NullPointer Exception, then what is the use of .filter(Objects :: nonNull) just after that? And if there are 2 courses in the semester, only they would be streamed and not anything null. I am just trying to understand the use of the first 'filter(Objects :: nonNull).

Comment: An empty but not null `Iterable` doesn't produce a `NullPointerException`. Just the stream operations do nothing with. It is like iterating with a `for` with a empty `Iterable` : no exception is thrown. I update with comment.

Comment: Got you. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean allCourseHaveEmptyStudens=semester.getCourses().stream()
.allMatch(c-> c.getStudents()==null || c.getStudents().size==0)
;
```

I think it's enough to fulfill your requirement.

Note: It might get a compilation error because I don't use editor tool.

Comment: I need to know if there are zero students in all the courses combined. I don;t want to know if any of the courses has zero students, i need to know in all if there are zero students.